# how do I append this two arrays without crashing my RAM?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

if I try to append train_images and new_imgs my RAM crashes. I tried to transform train_images to a regular list but the same issue. also when I try to append the image (batch[0]) it takes about two seconds for a complete batch, which is not acceptable. There is not error message. There is no error message, the program just does not respond and then just closes and I need to run it again, but every time some issue.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x  
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

I have installed the dataset and preproccecd the data:

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = 
datasets.cifar10.load_data()

train_images = train_images / 255.0;
```

created an image data generator:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rotation_range=40,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True,
fill_mode='nearest')
```

I have created an array to store all of the modified images, and then started looping through all of my dataset and reshape my data to be ready to be modified:

```
new_images = []
for num, test_img in enumerate(train_images):
  img = image.img_to_array(test_img)
  img = img.reshape((1,) + img.shape)
```

I have ran the reshaped images through the image data generator and stored then in the array:

```
  i = 0
  print(str(num) + ' out of ' + str(len(train_images)) + ' left')
  for batch in datagen.flow(img):
      new_images.append(batch[0])
      i += 1
      if i > 4:
          break
```

and now I can't get the arrays to append in any way without crashing my 12 GB of RAM...

Comment: "my RAM crashes" Can you be more specific? Can you add the error message? Also, does "12 RAM" mean 12 GB of ram allocated/available for the application?

Answer (score 0):

> I have created an array to store all of the modified images

There's not need to store the generated images, just use `.fit(...)` and `.flow(...)` methods.

```
datagen.fit(train_images)

model.fit(datagen.flow(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=32),
          steps_per_epoch=len(train_images) / 32, epochs=epochs)
```

[ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class)